# Dokku/Docker out of disk space - How to enter app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dokku

So my question is I have an errant rails app deployed using Dokku with the default Digital Ocean setup. This rails app has eaten all of the disk space as I did not set up anything to clean out the `/tmp` directory.

So the output of `df` is:

`Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1506176        0   1506176   0% /dev
tmpfs             307356    27488    279868   9% /run
/dev/vda1       60795672 60779288         0 100% /
tmpfs            1536772        0   1536772   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1536772        0   1536772   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15        106858     3419    103439   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs             307352        0    307352   0% /run/user/0`

So I am out of disk space, but I don't know how to enter the container to clean it. Any `dokku ****` return `/home/dokku/.basher/bash: main: command not found
Access denied` which I have found out is because I am completely out of HD space.

So 2 questions.

1: How do I get into the container to clear the tmp directory

2: Is there a way to set a max disk size limit so Dokku doesn't eat the entire HD again?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also facing this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dokku uses docker to deploy your application, you are probably accumulating a bunch of stale docker images, which over time can take over all of your disk space.

Try running this:

```
docker image ls
```

Then try removing unused images:

```
docker system prune -a
```

For more details, see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes

Comment: I've continued to prune images but the space has continued to be consumed, now there's nothing left to prune and I'm out of space. I wonder if this is due to storage and logs being kept?

Comment: @CTS_AE you're likely retaining deployment volumes, dokku doesn't clear that stuff by itself for some obscure reason. If you continuously deploy on that dokku instance set a crontab to run `docker volumes prune` daily at midnight or something